# create index using openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distributed

How do I create an index on a table that exist in a remote SQL Server database using the openquery syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can't on your side. The index must be added to a local object only. You can't use an indexed view either.

You *can* ask the other party to add an index for you to their table...

Edit:
Expanding John's answer... You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'CREATE INDEX etc;SELECT 0 AS foobar')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain however I suspect that this cannot be done.

OPENQUERY is intended to return a Result Set and so is unlikely to accept DDL statements.

See the Microsoft Books Online reference for examples of acceptable usage scenarios.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx