# Passthrough Query from one SQL Server to another that drops a table on the source

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery, pass-through

I have a SQL Server in Spain and one in the US and there is a domain trust between the two with linked servers on each for access to the other.

I would like to be able to run the below query on the US SQL Server without having to maintain a stored proc on the US Server in order to run it.  Is there a way to create a passthrough query from the SQL Server in Spain?  I've already tried using OPENQUERY and OPENROWSET and it's just not working as they only seem to work with select statements that return results:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Global].[dbo].[WW_Customer_Receivables]

SELECT * 

INTO [global].[dbo].[ww_customer_receivables]

FROM 
    [LinkedServerObject-Spain].[global].dbo.ww_customer_receivables
```

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure to run  the above?

Comment: Why drop the destination table and recreate it, instead of just running a TRUNCATE on the destination table?

Comment: I'm doing a drop and insert into because if I have to add new columns in the future I will only have to add them in one spot.  I manage a LOT of infrastructure so always have to keep an eye out for ways to reduce maintenance overhead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute DDL statement on your linked server with `openquery` you can with the following trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, '
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Global].[dbo].[WW_Customer_Receivables]
SELECT @@RowCount')
```

The `SELECT @@RowCount` returns a result set. So `OPENQUERY` works.
This trick works for all DDL operations like create, alter, drop. Or if you want to perform inserts/updates/deletes that don't return a result set.

Same trick is applied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109476/create-index-using-openquery/1109511) Where they have a dummy select foobar.

If you want to execute the `into` statement from the `openquery` you can do it like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Global].[dbo].[WW_Customer_Receivables]

SELECT *
INTO [global].[dbo].[ww_customer_receivables]
FROM OPENQUERY([LinkerServerObject-US], '
    SELECT *
    FROM [global].dbo.ww_customer_receivables')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I appreciate it.  I ran this query from the Spain server ```sql
 SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(linked-Spain-to-US], '
DROP TABLE [Global].[pbi].[WW_Customer_Receivables]
SELECT @@RowCount') ``` and it doesn't drop the table.  I did a trace and it shows up there but just doesn't drop the table and I get no error codes.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it’s a transaction? Or do you have a distributed transaction coordinator involved?

Comment: Or try without the if exist?